# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, where $a_n \geq 0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^p$ converges for all $p \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

> Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, where $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n\in N$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^p$ converges for all $p \geq 1$

Proof. $b_n \geq a_n$ for all $n \in n_o$ then $\sum a_n => a_n$ converges to 0 for all $n \geq n_o$ thus,  0$\leq$ $a_n$ $\leq$ 1 then $a_n^p \leq a_n$,
 $a_n^p$ converges.

Is that good or do I need to add more?

Comment: The argument is good, but should be better written (e.g. replace the "...$a_n\to 0$ for all $n\geq n_0$" with "since $\sum a_n$ converges, there exists $n_0$ such that $a_n<1$ for all $n\geq n_0$"...)

Answer (score 1):

> $b_n \geq a_n$ for all $n \in n_o$

1. What is $b_n$? You haven't said anything about $b_n$. Symbols should not appear in the proof without any introduction/explanation. "Let $b_n=a_n^p$" would be a way to introduce $b_n$.
2. $n\in n_0$ should be $n\ge n_0$
3. What is $n_0$? You haven't said anything about $n_0$. Symbols should not appear in the proof without any introduction/explanation. "There exists $n_0$ such that..."  would be a way to introduce $n_0$.

> then $\sum a_n => a_n$ converges to $0$ for all $n \geq n_o$

"converges to $0$ for all $n \geq n_0$" is meaningless: a sequence either converges to $0$ or it does not; it can't converge only for some $n$.

Also, $\sum a_n \implies ...$ was probably meant to be $\sum a_n<\infty \implies ...$

> thus,  $0\leq a_n \leq  1$

**This** is where you want something with $n\ge n_0$.